# What were Riemann's greatest contributions to the field of abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, math-history

Writing a short biography on him as a project for an abstract algebra course and I was wondering what people more familiar with the field would consider his greatest contributions to be. I'm currently looking into Riemann surfaces, but I'm not 100% sure that's a true "abstract algebra" application.

EDIT: I've been combing through a few history texts that my professor recommended but most of them focus on his contributions to geometry. I haven't been able to find anything other than the surfaces which seem to be related to abstract algebra. Part of the issue is I'm not sure what constitutes an abstract algebra application.

EDIT 2: I'll keep this question open just to see what people think, but for the time being I chose to give an overview of Riemann's major accomplishments (I chose his contributions to differential geometry, Riemann sums, and Riemann surfaces) and then decided to give extra focus to the Riemann hypothesis. I decided to make this edit just in case anyone was curious. I'll continue to read answers and will accept an answer as well.

Comment: What have you found already (apart from Riemann surfaces which has nothing to do with algebra)?

Comment: I've been combing through a few history texts that my professor recommended but most of them focus on his contributions to geometry. I haven't been able to find anything other than the surfaces which seem to be related to abstract algebra. Why do you say they aren't? Part of the issue is I'm not sure what constitutes an abstract algebra application.

Comment: Then it means that perhaps your professor wasn't expecting you to find anything specifically related to algebra.

Comment: That could be true but he outright says in the assignment description "talk a little about what your figure's contributions to abstract algebra were" so I'm not really looking to take the chance. I'd also like to know simply for my own knowledge. I'm not really looking for anything in-depth, even just naming a couple things that I could then go and research would be for me a more than satisfactory answer to this question.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why I'm being downvoted, some education and less caginess would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's often the case with so short questions, perhaps because people are getting the impression that you are after a quick way to get your homework done for you. Perhaps include your answer to my first question into the body of the OP?

Comment: Done. I'm not looking for my homework to be done for me, seeing as I don't expect anyone here to write a paper. I'm really just looking for a 5-6 word answer that could direct me towards a research topic.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me.  That might not be saying much.  It seems like there were a lot of specific instances where abstract algebra was used in Riemannian Geometry,  on second thought.   How about homology and homotopy groups of Riemannian manifolds.  Maybe one could find the fundamental group of a Riemann surface.  How about the deck group?  I mean, I don't know of any specific instances,  but didn't one thing lead to another.

Comment: How about number theory,  and the Riemann-Zeta function?

Comment: Thanks for those shouts, some of that sounds beyond the scope of the course but at least its something to look into. I agree that it seems really tough to specific applications for whatever reason - Riemann wasn't exactly known for his abstract algebra work it seems.

Comment: So yeah on the Riemann-Zeta function - is that considered "abstract algebra"? I'm having trouble delineating the different fields of mathematics in comparison to each other. What is the difference between "analytic number theory" and "abstract algebra" in this case?

Comment: How about algebraic number theory?   Also, there are applications to complex analysis,  where it seems he was rather prominent.  It's an interesting question,  and, as I said, it seems more like he laid groundwork where there could then be applications (of abstract algebra).  Analytic number theory involves calculus,  as far as I know.

Comment: Gauß was his advisor,  and they both did things that were so fundamental and, I want to say, seminal.

Comment: Hm. This hasn't gotten any clearer to be honest, although I appreciate the help. I may just turn in the rough draft with a discussion on contributions of his that later had confirmed abstract algebra application and then go speak with my professor for further clarification.

Comment: To be honest, when I think of abstract algebra Riemann does not come to mind at all. Galois, Abel, Cayley, Gauss, Kummer, Dedekind, Noether---these were the mathematicians who pioneered abstract algebra and were more or less contemporaries of Riemann. I think of Riemann's contributions as being in the areas of analysis (real and complex), geometry, and analytic number theory.

Answer (score 2):

There exists an equivalence of categories between compact Riemannian surfaces $\mathcal{C}$ and algebraic function fields $\mathcal{F}$ in one variable over $\Bbb C$, given by $\mathcal{C}\mapsto \mathcal{M(C)}$, the field of meromorphic functions. In this sense, I suppose, we could also mention the "algebra" context for Riemannian surfaces. However, it is also clear that they belong mainly to geometry and not to abstract algebra.

Comment: Plus, the language of categories is not what Riemann would have used.